# Want my UITextView only to be scroll enabled when editing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can't get changing the scroll option based on different criteria to work for my project.

I have a TableViewController with different cells. Some of these cells includes an empty UITextView. When scrolling up and down the TableView, it's annoying when hitting a textView and trying to scroll, it's the empty TextView which is scrolling and not the TableView.

My solution for this is to just disable the scroll for the TextView and then enable it when start editing. However I can't get this to work. I have unchecked the "Scrolling Enabled" and implemented the following lines for the cells holding the TextView:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView*)textView {
    [self.textView setScrollEnabled:YES]; }

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView*)textView {
    [self.textView setScrollEnabled:NO]; }
```

I have debugged this in xcode and the code is executed as expected. But the scroll isn't enabled for the TextView when I'm entering text. What am I missing?

I even added the following to check the status of the scroll-option:

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView*)textView {
    BOOL scrollStatus = self.bodyText.scrollEnabled;
    BOOL scrollStatusInput = textView.scrollEnabled;
}
```

I can see that the scrollEnabled is 'YES' in both lines. But I can't still can't scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the delegate by:

```
cell.textView.delegate = self;
```

And one thing, you are doing

```
[self.textView setScrollEnabled:YES];
```

does self.textView contains the reference of your tableViewCell's textView?? If it does it should work, else you need to keep the reference of TableViewCell's textView. Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Thank you for the respons. However, still not working. The code I have is for the cells m-file, and the self.textView is referring to the cells textView. Also I expect the 'cell.textView.delegate = self;' should be 'self.textView.delegate = self;' in my case - sorry if some of this seems plain forward, but still pretty new to objective c.